# VBA.FileSystem Dir

Tags: vba, vb6

In VB6 code i m using VBA.FileSystem.Dir to get file name from a directory path. But it is returning empty string. Please find the below code

```
Call getFile.ShowOpen //getFile is CommonDialog Control of VB6

txtFile.Text = getFile.FileTitle //Correct file name is returned
If Dir(getFile.filename) == "" Then
     // Conditions come true..But ideally it should not!!!
```

But the file resides in some network location. Can there be any permission issue? If yes, How do i see that file in getFile.ShowOpen dialog and Dir() returns empty string?

Any help on what is wrong in the above code

Comment: What is the actual value of `cdFile.FileName`? (Hint: use a debugger to find out.) Does a file exist at that location in your file system? (Hint: use Explorer to find out.)

Comment: Yes... the file exists. I can select the file in getFile.ShowOpen dialog.
But the file exists in other network drive

Comment: I have my doubts that VB6 would/could use VBA type libraries. VBA is a subset of VB, not the other way around. VB6 should have its own FileSystem functions (http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/working-file-system-vb6) But looking at the code snippet you provide I do have to wonder where cdFile.filename comes from? Are you sure that's returning the value you expect? What if you use Dir(txtFile.Text) instead?

Comment: Cindy, i guess we can use VBA.FileSystem libraries in VB6 because the above code works for other files.
Sorry it should have been getFile instead of cdFile and yes it is returning correct file path.
Can't use Dir(txtFile.Text), because it has just file name and not the file path

But the file resides in some network location. 
Can there be any permission issue? If yes, How do i see that file in getFile.ShowOpen dialog

Comment: Can you share the value of getFile.filename? Is this the real code - capitalization of filename is incorrect.

Comment: One of VB6's typelibs is called VBA but that has nothing to do with VBA as used in Office applications, etc.  This was probably just given the same name to aid in transporting source code from one world to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these points:

1. afaik, the double equal ( == ) is not supported in vb6
2. Dir = (whatever) can return ""
   if whatever is a directory or hidden file

You could trap just the name by using 
  If Dir(whatever, vbDirectory Or vbHidden Or vbArchive Or vbNormal)

But you would still have to test each to see what it was.

btw, it's better to have a variable to receive Dir and inspect that, rather than inspecting Dir itself.

```
dim sTgt$
sTgt = Dir(whatever)
```

Also, btw, an alternative to chking each type is to to inspect FileLen.

Curiously, FileLen was not affected by the Hidden/Sys attribs, although it will err out if the file does not exist.

So, (and this is really old hacking stuff but handy code).

If you declare a variable for FileLen

```
Dim lfLen&
'and have some error coding
On Error resume next

'and then just inspect the target
lfLen = FileLen(stgt)

if lflen > 0 then 
... do things

(or if hacking)
... binary open
```

Because, If the file no exist,
  a directory will return 0, 
  but if file = archive, hidden, sys it will return bytes.

hth

Gary

Comment: Don't forget the `vbReadOnly` flag.

Comment: Yes Bob, quite correct.  I was kinda air coding and thinking 'I know there's another param' but I'm sure some will notice.   ;-)